# IOS/Storyboard/Autolayout: Center round button under horizontal bar

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard

This should be incredibly simple but somehow has proven incredibly complicated for me with auto layout.
I have a horizontal bar shaped button.  I want to center a round information icon below it.  Auto layout keeps trying to stretch the round button into an oval and is not centering it from left to right as in the following:

[image]

The above is the result of the following constraints that should work but don't.

[image]

Can anyone please tell me the correct constraints to add to accomplish this simple task.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you set `imageView.contentMode = .center`? Also, if possible, can you upload your project to somewhere so we can see how you've set your constraints?

Comment: The constraints are shown in the image above.

Comment: I think I got it to work.  I fixed the width and height of the icon and now it now longer puts it off to the left.  Not that it makes any sense whatsoever but it is displaying in the middle and no longer stretched.

Comment: Normally you shouldn't fix the height and width because image view knows its size intrinsically based on the image it displays so it should be enough to set `contentMode`.

Comment: In the console, are there any autolayout/constraint warnings?

Answer (score 0):

If the image is being stretched, then set its contentMode to be aspectFit or aspectFill.

Once that is done, you can add a constraint to the image so that it and the login button share vertical centers.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see this yellow box showing in your view? It's showing a warning that means the view which is selected right now should be placed here according to the defined constraints. I guess the constraints of this view are conflicting with other views. Try to resolve this warning by adding "suggested" constraints or by fixing misplacement. I hope it'll work, if not then give me your code I'll resolve that issue for you.

[image]